# Protractor syncing to an Angular page after redirection to Auth0 non-Angular page

Tags: angular, oauth, protractor

I have an Angular web app that uses Protractor for e2e tests.  I recently added OAuth0  authentication. I disable Angular synchronisation before redirection to the non-Angular OAuth0 page using await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) and that works fine. However I cannot reenable Angular synchronisation using await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true) again for the rest of that spec file test suite or I get the infamous protractor timeout errors.  I'd like to re-enable Angular synchronisation as otherwise I have to use expected conditions, waits and sleeps to ensure follow-on pages are loaded and that can result in intermittent errors.

I have read all the questions and answers and have tried all the obvious - reloading the page, getting a new page, waits, long sleeps, etc, etc.

So my question is quite specific rather than looking for suggestions - does anyone understand the mechanism Protractor uses to sync with Angular pages and do you know whether it possible or not for Angular to resync after a redirection out to, and back from, a non Angular page, i.e. am I wasting my time looking for a fix.  I read up a little on the mechanism - it loads a script to be run on the page but I'm unsure why that can't be loaded again when I do a browser.get{'/') after returning from the auth0 redirection.

Note that I can leave Angular synchronisation disabled and can get things to work so I am not asking for advice on just how to get things working.  If you have faced the specific problem and come up with a fix I'd love to hear it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: May I say, this is an excellently worded question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer - yes you can reenable angular in protractor. However, protractor doesn't always work with angular apps. So just make sure protractors synchronization will be working as it should with your app AND the page is ready for this.

First, manually open the app, and get authorized. Then in console run `getAllAngularTestabilities()`. If this command in not available, **protractor can't work with angular**. If the command is successful, take a look at returned object, specifically at `hasPendingMacrotasks` and `hasPendingMicrotasks` properties of `obj[0]._ngZone`. If any of them is `true`, **protractor can't work with this page**. If both of them are `false` then you can proceed to the next step

Now, when you now the page can talk to protractor with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)` you need to implement the following method for your tests

```
let login = async function (username, password) {
  await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  await browser.get(url);
  await $usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
  await $passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
  await $loginButton.click();
  // MOST IMPORTANTLY, YOU HAVE TO WAIT UNTIL YOUR APP FULLY LOADED
  await browser.wait(
    // whatever you need to wait for,
    timeout,
    'failure message'
  );
  // AND FINALLY
  await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
}
```

I mean you don't have to have this method, I just showed you the order of actions you have to follow to achieve your results.

Basically, the point is, when you login, make sure the non-angular login page is gone, and your angular page is fully loaded before reenabling waiting for angular.

Two approaches you could use:

- wait for all key elements to be present
- or write a function which will be returning `return !obj[0]._ngZone.hasPendingMacrotasks && !obj[0]._ngZone.hasPendingMicrotasks` and pass it to the `browser.wait`

Comment: Thanks much for that.  It was very helpful to debug.  It appears that when the createAuth0Client method of the auth0-spa-js SDK (which is used to implement Auth0 authentication on an Angular SPA app) is called following redirect from the Auth0 site (after successful authentication) that hasPendingMacroTasks is set to true and is never reset.  That prevents Protactor syncing as you explain above.

Answer (score 0):

My answer as fyi for all:

It appears that when the createAuth0Client method of the auth0-spa-js SDK (which is used to implement Auth0 authentication on an Angular SPA app) is called following redirect from the Auth0 site (after successful authentication) that hasPendingMacroTasks is set to true and is never reset.  That prevents Protractor syncing as explained above.

I refactored my implementation of the auth0-spa-js to match the latest guide on the Auth0 website (using Observables as opposed to async-await) and the exact same problem exists.

I looked into what createAuth0Client is doing:  It has gotten a JWT (token) from the Auth0 server before it redirects to the app and when it is called it caches that token and sets a timer to delete that cache entry.   The setTimeout call in createAuth0Client is wrapped by Angular Zone and that holds hasPendingMacroTasks true which prevents Protractor from getting notification that Angular has completed loading.  The timer is set to the lifetime of the token which is a setting one sets in the Auth0 server so I tested this by setting the token timeout to 3s and hasPendingMacroTasks was reset to false and Protractor successfully sync'd after I waited 5s in my e2e tests.   However Protractor would have to log in on the Auth0 server again once the timer expires before it can make API calls so shortening the timer is not a feasible workaround.

I looked into running createAuth0Client outside the Angular NgZone but that proved extremely difficult if not impossible:

1. You need access to the created Auth0 client instance and once you make it available in NgZone you see the hasPendingMacroTasks set to true again.
2. You can't just make the SDK methods (eg login, logout) available back in NgZone as they need the client instance context to run
   ( I don't think you can hold state (the Auth0 client instance) outside the Angular zone and access it when you need it).
3. You can't create a client instance and run an SDK function outside the Angular zone every time you need to run an SDK function as if you create more than one client instance you can get errors.

Comment: This is exactly why I always just disable the `waitForAngular` stuff. I've never had good luck with it. Too many variables that can prevent it from actually working right. It's easier to just disable and then use `ExpectedConditions` and some custom wait functions to make sure the page is ready.