# I can't automate Angular project with protractor

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

i'm trying to automate a project in Angular, but is just working the browser.get, because when I want to click a element searching with id, the script doesn't work, return a timeout.

So I try with async/await, also with sleeps, but is just working with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);`

i want to test the project without that line, because is a project angular, so i don't know what i'm doing bad. That's the code of Protrator conf.js, spec and Page

[image]

[image: My protractor.conf.js]

[image]

Please help me to know how to automate an angular app without disable Angular, if I delete that line page doesn't show that clicks the button and pass the it, what I'm doign wrong.
Thanks

Comment: this is why https://stackoverflow.com/a/57664113/9150146 protractor doesn't work on all angular page

Comment: So, what I have to do? deactivate APM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was deactivate the APM of the project. because is sending http requests and the angular is waiting to those requests.