# Protractor timeout on Angular 6 navigation

Tags: angular, protractor

I am trying to use Protractor to test a simple login function and everything looks correct when the browser pops up but the test fails anyway.

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import {browser, by, element, ProtractorBrowser} from 'protractor';

describe('new App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should login successfully', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    element(by.id('email')).element(by.tagName('input')).sendKeys('email');
    element(by.id('password')).element(by.tagName('input')).sendKeys('password');

    element(by.id('login-button')).click()

    browser.sleep(3000).then(() => {
      browser.getCurrentUrl().then(actualUrl => {
        expect(actualUrl).toEqual('/clients')
      })
    })

  })
});
```

The page correctly fills in the form and navigates to `/clients` however the logs say:

```
**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) new App should login successfully
  - Failed: script timeout
    (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689}),platform=Mac OS X 10.15.5 x86_64)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe protractor doesn't work on your page with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)` check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57664113/9150146

Comment: please upvote if that answered your question