# Protractor - Timeout Error with Angular application

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

While handling angular application, if the browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true) then I'm getting the below error while clicking an element:

```
ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout
(Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
Driver info: chromedriver=85.0.4183.38 (9047dbc2c693f044042bbec5c91401c708c7c26a-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#779}),platform=Windows NT x86_64)
```

Below is the root element

```
< app-root _nghost="" ng-version="8.0.0">
```

Even after updating the root element as below in the config file, I'm getting the same error:

```
rootElement: 'app-root'
```

Note: I don't want to go for browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) since I want to make use of all the Protractor features.

1. Whether waitForAngularEnabled should set to true while saving the data or during navigation alone?
2. What needs to be done to identify the application as angular from Protractor?

Answer (score 0):

Not ALL angular pages may use protractor features. Refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57664113/9150146 to see how to find out if your page can use it or not