# protractor test times out with D3.js and DC.js graph library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jasmine, protractor, dc.js

Recently my application has been upgraded to use JavaScript D3 graph library (D3.js and DC.js), and since then Protractor test started timing out with this error :

```
- Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/configuration-parser.js:27

node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/configuration-parser.js:27
      internal/timers.js:554:17
node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/configuration-parser.js:27
      jasmine-spec-reporter: unable to open 'internal/timers.js'
node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/configuration-parser.js:27
      Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'internal/timers.js'
node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/configuration-parser.js:27

node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/configuration-parser.js:27
      internal/timers.js:497:7
node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/configuration-parser.js:27
      jasmine-spec-reporter: unable to open 'internal/timers.js'
node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/configuration-parser.js:27
      Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'internal/timers.js'
```

I tried many things like increasing the timeouts, adding sleeps or expected conditions to wait for elements etc. but every time my test just hangs on these charts and then timeouts.

If I run same test on older version of the Application test works perfectly fine. I also verified that there are no Identifier changes, but not sure what is causing test to hang.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57664113/9150146

Comment: I tried the commands you explained in the above link and here is the output : `ngZone: e {hasPendingMicrotasks: false, hasPendingMacrotasks: false, isStable: true, onUnstable: t, onMicrotaskEmpty: ` for `obj[0]._ngZone.` my test started hanging on this page from the time Chart and Graph library has been updated to D3.js and DC.js

Comment: have you tried disabling waiting for angular by `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`?

Comment: yes, tried that option also but did not help.

Comment: then it's not related to what you think. you probably waiting for an element that doesn't exist. You need to debug the script to find that element

Comment: Elements are present, I verified that. the only problem with my app is these Charts/ graphs are getting drawn twice, and some how protractor is not able to handle that.

Comment: just added detailed logs to my question if that will help in identifying the problem.

Comment: did you check why it's complaining about `internal/timers.js`?

Comment: I am not really sure, why its complaining about internal/timers.js.

Comment: I would start with this. Chances are that resolving this error will resolve your issue

Comment: Any luck? hitting the same issue (a lot of console noise)

Comment: @Antoniossss , we just updated all our tests to async await, and that helped with these timeout issues.

Comment: thank you, we also updated tests to async await.